# What should be in a Maven application.properties file in order to create a runnable jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

**Notice to future readers:** When I created this question, I was unaware, due to my misunderstanding a confusing section in the linked guide, that the application.properties file is separate from the MANIFEST.MF file, and that the latter is generated by maven no matter what. See the answer below for how to create a runnable jar.

I am currently trying to learn the basics of Maven by going through the [Getting Started Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html). When I reached [the section on non-class resources](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR) in a jar file, however, I noticed that an essential piece of information is missing. The guide says that one way to create a manifest file, in order to make the jar executable, is to create an application.properties file in the resource section of the Maven project. It gives no information, however, on what goes inside this file, or how one specifies the main class.

What information can I place inside the application.properties file? What is the format of this file? Is it a standard Java .properties file? If so, what are the valid properties? How can I specify the main class in the artifact such that the resulting jar from `mvn package` is runnable via `java -jar`?

I have tried various search terms (ie. "Maven application.properties file") with no useful answers. I have also looked through the rest of the Getting Started guide and somewhat cursorily the rest of the Maven website, for I do not yet know enough Maven to properly understand most of it.

Comment: "The guide says that one way to create a manifest file, in order to make the jar executable, is to create an application.properties file in the resource section of the Maven project". I've read through the whole section and I can't see that anywhere. Can you provide a link and quote please? As far as I can tell, the file is just an irrelevant sample properties file used to show how the standard directory layout works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Upon further examination in order to answer your question, I realized a mistake that I had made. Because the guide was introducing the application.properties file and making note of the manifest file at the same time, I assumed they were connected. It turns out they are not. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I highly recommend deleting this question as it is more likely to confuse than help future visitors.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have added a notice at the top for future readers. Because I do think that the section in the Maven guide is setup in such a way as to predispose readers to my misunderstanding, I think it is better to leave the question findable with the notice at the tp.

Comment: I disagree completely about the guide being unclear there, but it's entirely your call.

Comment: @john01dav If this guide is confusing I would recommend to open a ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MNGSITE/ and tell what is confusing and how it should be improved ...and it could be that it is not very clear..so best is to let people know that it could be improved...

Answer (score 1):

To make a jar executable, you specify the `main class` in the assembly plugin.

Example pom snippit:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.maventest.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't answer part of the question. Specifically, it does not address the contents of the application.properties file.

Comment: Followed the link.  The application.properties file is just a text file to maven.  It's an example to show ${} property replacement and including resources in jars.  It has no special meaning.  Making a jar executable is done as above or using a custom manifest file

Comment: Adding that to the answer would make it good, and ready to accept. Ideally, it could note that the manifest file is handled separately (see my comment on the question).